# Is any reference in the Quran about recreational hunting?

Tags: halal-haram, quran, sports, hunting

There are two types of hunting, first is for food, second is recreational. Nowadays mostly hunting is recreational (unless you live in a very remote area). I want to know if there is any reference from Quran about recreational hunting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules of of Islam is taught to people who hunt, i.e. : they did not playing around, they kill but there is no intention to be eaten or utilized (it's not allowed in islam).

There are many hadiths that explain about the rules of hunting such as :

"Allah has ordained kindness (or excellence) in everything. If killing is to be done, do it in the best manner, and when you slaughter, do it in the best manner by first sharpening the knife, and putting the animal at ease" (hadith narrated by by Muslim).

"If someone kills a sparrow for sport, the sparrow will cry out on the Day of Judgement, 'O Lord! That person killed me in vain! He did not kill me for any useful purpose" (Nisai).

"Any part cut off a living animal is dead flesh" (Ahmad, Abu Dawud, Tirmidhi, Hakim).

"Whoever kills a sparrow or anything bigger than that without a just cause, Allah will hold him accountable on the Day of Judgement. The listeners asked, O Messenger of Allah, what is a just cause? He replied, That he will kill it to eat, not simply to chop off its head and then throw it away" (Nisai, Hakim).

"When you set your dog (for the chase), mention the name of Allah, if he catches the game, and you reach it while it is still alive, cuts, its throat" (Bukhari, Muslim).

"If you send your dog after the game, and it eats part of it, you should not eat of it, for the dog has hunted for itself and not for you; but if you send the dog and it kills the game without eating it, you can eat it, as it has caught it for its master" (Ahmad, Bukhari, Muslim).

and described in Surah Al-Mā'idah 5:1
[image]

"O you who have believed, fulfill [all] contracts. Lawful for you are the animals of grazing livestock except for that which is recited to you [in this Qur'an] - hunting not being permitted while you are in the state of ihram. Indeed, Allah ordains what He intends"

and described in Surah Al-Mā'idah 5:96 (The Table Spread) - سورة المائدة

[image]

"Lawful to you is game from the sea and its food as provision for you and the travelers, but forbidden to you is game from the land as long as you are in the state of ihram. And fear Allah to whom you will be gathered"