# Is there a hadith "whoever shoots at a living creature for sport is cursed" and is it authentic?

Tags: hadith, source-identification, authenticity, sports, hunting

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animals_in_Islam) references a hadith from page 874 of *Encyclopedia of Religion and Nature* by Bron Taylor ([Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=i4mvAwAAQBAJ)) which writes:

> He opposed recreational hunting, saying that "whoever shoots at a living creature for sport is cursed."

However, this book has no reference.  Googling [`whoever shoots at a living creature for sport is cursed`](https://www.google.com/#q=whoever+shoots+at+a+living+creature+for+sport+is+cursed) doesn't help further than this.

**Question**: Is there a hadith "whoever shoots at a living creature for sport is cursed" and is it authentic?

Comment: The answer to the related question https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/7901/22 quotes some ahadith with a similar meaning, but not that particular one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is an authentic hadith to that effect in Sahih Muslim in the book of hunting, slaughter, and what may be eaten:

> #### حَدَّثَنِي زُهَيْرُ بْنُ حَرْبٍ، حَدَّثَنَا هُشَيْمٌ، أَخْبَرَنَا أَبُو بِشْرٍ، عَنْ سَعِيدِ بْنِ جُبَيْرٍ، قَالَ مَرَّ ابْنُ عُمَرَ بِفِتْيَانٍ مِنْ قُرَيْشٍ قَدْ نَصَبُوا طَيْرًا وَهُمْ يَرْمُونَهُ وَقَدْ جَعَلُوا لِصَاحِبِ الطَّيْرِ كُلَّ خَاطِئَةٍ مِنْ نَبْلِهِمْ فَلَمَّا رَأَوُا ابْنَ عُمَرَ تَفَرَّقُوا فَقَالَ ابْنُ عُمَرَ مَنْ فَعَلَ هَذَا لَعَنَ اللَّهُ مَنْ فَعَلَ هَذَا إِنَّ رَسُولَ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم لَعَنَ مَنِ اتَّخَذَ شَيْئًا فِيهِ الرُّوحُ غَرَضًا
>
> Sa'id b. Jubair reported that Ibn 'Umar happened to pass by some young men of the Quraish who had tied a bird (and th, is made it a target) at which they had been shooting arrows Every arrow that they missed came into the possession of the owner of the bird. So no sooner did they see Ibn 'Umar they went away. Thereupon Ibn 'Umar said: Who has done this? Allah has cursed him who does this. **Verily Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) invoked curse upon one who made a live thing the target (of one's marksmanship).**
>
> <sub>— [Sahih Muslim 1958 b](https://www.sunnah.com/muslim/34/91/)</sub>

Comment: Thanks.  I updated Wikipedia with this instead.

Comment: It seems my Wikipedia edit was reversed: "Better to use secondary sources when possible rather than quoting directly from ahadith".  This is strange to me, the sunnah.com reference is far more reliable.  Hmm...

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones — What sourced are required? I can provide printed sources' references if this is what they want.